# trying to make textView with initial text in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm want that my textview text look similar to this:

para1:

para2:

so that text will be in bold text style and specific font, and in run time i want that other text will be in deferent style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to use NSAttributedString for that, find the RunningAppHere which helps in changing the color of a word, similarly you can change the font

The point is use **NSAttributedString**

Scan through the word and find the range of your word and change its color.

```
- (IBAction)colorWord:(id)sender {
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.text.text];

NSArray *words=[self.text.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString *word in words) {        
    if ([word hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
        NSRange range=[self.text.text rangeOfString:word];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];           
    }
}
[self.text setAttributedText:string];
}
```